# rails : return the two different joined results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my user model the searching perform based on "role" for the role=4 i need to return two combined results , but its only return the last result(User.tempexaminee_users) how can i join these results.in the if role ==4

> **def self.search(search,role)**
>
> **if role == 3**
>    **User**.questionsetter_users.where(['login LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ? and role_id = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{    search}%",    role])
>
> **end**
>
> **if role == 4**
>   **User**.examinee_users.where(['login LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR email LIKE
>   ? and role_id = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%",role])
>   **User**.tempexaminee_users.where(['login LIKE ? OR name
>   LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
>
> **end**
>
> **end**

Combined result have to return on the step if role == 4.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Do you want two types of result- one where `role_id = role`, and another where you are not checking for `role_id`? For this u can just write one line instead of the two `User.examinee_users.where(['login LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ? OR role_id = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%",role])`

Comment: User.examinee_users.where(['login LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ? and role_id = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%",role]) it fetches some record where the role= 4  (imagine 10 records)   User.tempexaminee_users.where(['login LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"]) this will also fetch some record (5 records)  so the total 15 record have to return (( now the 5 record only return)) i want to combine and want to sent.